# Best data structure to represent grocery items in C#?

Tags: c#

What's the best data structure for a 2D array of size unknown x 2. Which means one dimension is dynamic (list of grocery items) and the other is fixed (price and quantity).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I would use a `List<T>`, with T being a custom class.

This would be something like:

```
public class GroceryItem { 
   public string Name { get; set; }
   // ...
}
public class PurchaseLineItem
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public GroceryItem Item { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then just do:

```
List<PurchaseLineItem> items = new List<PurchaseLineItem>();
```

This gives you the flexibility to have your price and quanities, for any number of items.  It's easy to add to this as needed, and make it as long as you want.

Comment: Nitpick - `Price` should be some kind of decimal type, to avoid problems with non-representable prices.

Comment: @Bi - if the properties were private, you wouldn't be able to access them outside of the class.  Notice the `{get; set;}` after each class "field" - this syntax is actually setting up properties backed by private, non-referenceable class fields.